# Unexpected color value error - WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, fragment-shader

Live Demo on [Shdr Editor](http://shdr.bkcore.com/#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). You will NEED to change the top right to cube and zoom in to see the effect properly.

Vertex Shader Code

```
precision highp float;
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
varying mat4 hash;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

  hash = mat4(
    ivec4(255, 0, 0, 0),
    ivec4(0, 0, 0, 0),
    ivec4(0, 0, 0, 0),
    ivec4(0, 0, 0, 0)
  );
}
```

Fragment Shader code

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
varying mat4 hash;

void main() {
  vec2 pos = vec2(
    floor(gl_FragCoord.x / (resolution.x / 16.0)),
    floor(gl_FragCoord.y / (resolution.y / 16.0))
  );

  int qrtID = int(floor(pos.y / 4.0));
  int rowID = int(mod(pos.y, 4.0));
  ivec4 quarter = qrtID == 0 ? ivec4(hash[0]) : qrtID == 1 ? ivec4(hash[1]) : qrtID == 2 ? ivec4(hash[2]) : ivec4(hash[3]);
  int row = rowID == 0 ? quarter[0] : rowID == 1 ? quarter[1] : rowID == 2 ? quarter[2] : quarter[3];
  float bit = floor(
    mod(
      float(float(row) / pow(2.0, pos.x)),
      2.0
    )
  );

  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(bit), 1.0);
}
```

The intention here is that when this is used, it will render to a 16x16 window, thus why I constrain it so. My hard coding of the `mat4` is temporary. The real life application of this code will generate intelligent values and uniform them in. Each `ivec4` represents a quarter of the screen (64 pixels); each `int` of a vector represents a row on the screen (16 pixels); each bit of an int represents one pixel. Thus the hard coded matrix value in `hash` should highlight the left half of the bottom row.

I'm thoroughly confused here, and I mostly need someone who hasn't seen my code before to have a look through it and find where I went wrong. I'm stumped at the frag shader last two lines, for `bit` is the floor of a value's mod 2: either 0 or 1, but what's rendered doesn't show that.